# Android App with ViewPager compiles but stops when setting image dynamically

Tags: android

If I remove the Image code lines, the App works, but if I put them in class DummySectionFragment It stopped when launching the App in simulator. How to fix this ?

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);


        ImageView image = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);

        return rootView;
    }
```

layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

        <ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/image"
   android:src="@drawable/image1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should use `rootView` instead of `getActivity()` because the fragment may not be attached to an activity yet.

Comment: dont forget to past stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the rootView to gather the ImageView.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
```

Fragments are different to Activitys.